# Comma necessary, optional, or incorrect after (this) restrictive clause?

Tags: commas

I am proofing an article and am wondering about the following sentence:

> The many – and at times quite explicit – references to the people into
> whose lives PARIS IS BURNING offered a glimpse, renew the questions
> around documentary ethics, looking relations, and power that have long
> surrounded Livingston’s film.

I really don't like the comma after glimpse but think I have read that one can be used to help with clarity/flow of a sentence. And I do understand that, if optional, consistency should be used throughout. But is the comma actually optional, necessary, or incorrect?

Comment: Upon which Supreme Authority of Righteousness in All Things English should the answer of your question depend?

Comment: The sentence is so convoluted that the comma doesn't matter.

Comment: I'd say the 'make a sentence classed by Hot Licks as convoluted enough to require separating into two or more' rule takes precedence. And do 'offer**ed**' and 'renew' match optimally, Phil? // If you have strict editing constraints, please understand that ELU tends to avoid 'second best' answers. (But the comma is a necessary crutch here IMO.)

Comment: I think you should try for a rewrite. Who or what is referencing these people?

Comment: Okay, the explicit references renew the ethical questions. But fix "looking relations" and I'm content.

Comment: @YosefBaskin — "looking relations" is a thing.

Comment: *The many and often explicit references to the lives glimpsed in* Paris Is Burning *renew the questions...*